# Git push to remote "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, git, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to push changes from my local machine to a live server. I followed the steps on [this page](http://toroid.org/git-website-howto).

On my **local machine**, here is what I get when I run: `$ git push web`

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 291 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: /bin/bash: GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git checkout -f: No such file or directory
To ssh://MyDomainRemoved.com/var/git/myproject.git
   d8a9173..7903ea9  master -> master
```

On the **live server**, the new commit shows in `$ git log`. It is having trouble with the *post-receive hook*. Here is what the post-receive file looks like right now:

```
#!/bin/bash GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git checkout -f
```

A few things I've already tried from other threads I've read:

- Tried `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/sh`
- Removed a hidden carriage return on the `#!/bin/bash` line. This allowed bash to run without an open error but still has the no such file error.
- Changing **/var/www/** to be owned by user **www-data**
- CHMOD **/var/www/** to **777** (still has the no such file error)

The server is Ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas of other things to try?

Comment: please include the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: @orvi sure here you go: `$ git remote -v`
`origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myusername/myproject.git (fetch)
origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myusername/myproject.git (push)
web ssh://root@MyDomainRemoved.com/var/git/myproject.git (fetch)
web ssh://root@MyDomainRemoved.com/var/git/myproject.git (push)`

Comment: where's your `post-recive` file locate?

Comment: @orvi It's in /var/git/myproject.git/hooks

Comment: okay. Now edit the `post-recieve` file like this way 

 `#!/bin/bash`
 `export GIT_DIR=/var/git/myproject/.git/`
 `export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/git/myproject/`
 `cd /var/git.myproject/`
  `git fetch`
 `git merge origin/master`
 `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: @orvi Thanks for your help on this. It looks like I may have been missing `GIT_DIR=` since that was the main addition to yours and @VonC's which ended up working. I chose VonC's though since it got the job done without the added commands that I may not have needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have your script on several lines instead of one:

```
#!/bin/bash 
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git checkout -f
```

The complete command would be:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/html --git-dir=/var/git/myproject/.git checkout -f
```

Comment: This works. Thank you @VonC! The final code was like yours but without the `/` in `/myproject/.git`